Cisco IP-Phone: Merging a Custom Rx Stream Into Call
I'm sending an RTPRx XSI command to a Cisco IP-Phone, in the following format:
<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="RTPRx:<Local-IP>:<Phone-Port>:100"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
This successfully starts a custom Rx stream on this phone-device, so my app could stream audio to it.
This works well. The streamed audio is well-heard at device's end.
While the device is during a phone-call (regular, peer-to-peer), when streaming audio to its custom Rx stream, this audio is (still) well heard at device's end, but is not heard to the other call-party.
Is there a way to accomplish that - making the other call-party hear the audio streamed into device's custom Rx stream?
Could the custom Rx stream be "bridged" into the call, possibly merged into device's Tx stream for this call?

I don't believe that is possible using the XSI streaming APIs.
You may need to look into CUCM JTAPI or TAPI, which have the ability to create conference calls (i.e. with an application controlled CTI Port phone device to play audio into the call).  The Agent Greeting feature is a simplified conference scenario that uses the phone's built-in-bridge DSP mixing capability, and may be a bit easier to implement.
This repo has some JTAPI samples demonstrating some of these pieces (e.g. conference and CTI Port): CiscoDevNet/jtapi-samples

Thanks for your response. Could phone's BiB be used to mix the custom Rx stream into the call? (by JTAPI, a direct phone-command or by ANY of Cisco's APIs)

And more generally - what are the possibilities for controlling phone's BiB mechanism, except JTAPI's addMediaStream method (i.e. its Agent Greeting feature)?

A custom Rx stream will be merged into an existing call, but only into the call's incoming audio - the far end will not hear the custom Rx stream audio.
The phone built-in-bridge is used by a a number of different CUCM and IPPS/XSI features, e.g. recording, coaching/whisper, agent greeting, IPPS media streaming, etc.  APIs are available to interact with those features of course, but there is no mechanism for more directly controlling the BiB itself at a low level, e.g. to implement novel audio mixing features (like an IPPS/XSI triggered agent greeting feature.)

Thanks much, @David Staudt, for your feedback.
As far as I know, Barge calls also involve phone's BiB, and are merged into phone's primary (customer-agent) call, only Barge is initiated by calling device's 'Barge' softkey.
Like you understood, I was seeking to "Barge" by software, and apparently - according to the info you supplied - this is not feasible.
I do believe that Cisco could and should add support for software-controlled Barge calls, and more generally - add IP-phone functionality/API for applying custom BiB usages, which help avoiding usage of CUCM conference resources.
